# Hiding form when submitted successfully

Tags: php, jquery, forms, validation, slidetoggle

I have a form which I want to hide when it's successfully submitted and display a message (which is already working). The only downside now is that the form is being slideToggled even if its not submitted correctly. There are some issues with submitting the form. It works weird. sometimes it submits if when not all fields are filled, sometimes it does not. I think the cooperation between php and jquery is not perfect here.

Thanks to help give I have managed to put this code together:

PHP:

```
<?php
      $receip = "office@avehire.co.uk";
      $subj = "Testimonial";
      $bodymsg = "Name: ".$_POST['name']."\n"
                   ."Company: ".$_POST['company']."\n"
                   ."Email: ".$_POST['email']."\n"
                   ."Message: ".$_POST['msg']."\n";

          if(!$_POST['msg'] || $_POST['name'] || $_POST['email']){
                 echo "<h6>Error sending e-mail<h6>";
                 exit;
          }

      $email = $_POST['email'];
      if(mail($receip, $subj, $bodymsg, 'From: Contact <'.$email.'>')){
        echo "<h6>Message sent successfully. Thank you for your feedback.</h6>";
      }
?>
```

HTML + elements of javascript:

```
<div id="feedback-form">

    <script>                    
        function submitmyform(){
            data=$('#myform').serialize();
                $.ajax({
                url: "scripts/form-testimonial.php",
                type:'POST',
                data:data,
                async:false,
                dataType:'html',
                success: function(msg){

                    $('#response_goes_here').html(msg);
                    $("#feedback-form").slideToggle(200);
                }
            });

        }
    </script>

    <form action="" id="myform">

        <ul>
            <li>    <label for="name">Name</label>              <input id="namef3" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" class="required"/>            
          </li>
            <li>    <label for="email">E-mail</label>           <input id="emailf3" name="email" type="text" placeholder="E-mail" class="required"/>        
          </li>
            <li>    <label for="company">Company</label>        <input id="companyf3" name="company" type="text" placeholder="Company (if applicable)" />   
          </li>
            <li>    <label for="msg">Message</label>            <textarea id="msgf3" name="msg" cols="43" rows="8" placeholder="Your feedback" class="required"></textarea> 
          </li>
        </ul>
        <button type="button" class="submit" onClick="submitmyform();">Send your feedback</button>
    </form>
</div> <!-- id="feedback-form" -->
    <div id="response_goes_here"></div>
```

and a validation script (sorry, its very long, I know):

```
$(function () {
var addErrorMessage = function (field) {
    var err = $(document.createElement('p')).addClass('validation-error').text('Required field');
    field.addClass('err').after(err);
},
clearError = function () {
    var t = $(this);
    if (t.hasClass('err')) {
        t.removeClass('err');
        t.next('p').empty().remove();
    }
},
isEmpty = function (str) {
    return str.trim().length < 1;
},
isValidEmail = function (str) {
    var regexp = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-\+])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
    return regexp.test(str);
},
fieldsValidate = false;

function validateForm(e) {
    console.log('validate start');
    var requiredFields = jQuery(e).find('.required');
    var email = jQuery(e).find('input[name="email"]');
    var emailValue = email.val();
    console.log(emailValue+' mail val');
    fieldsValidate = true;
    // check that required fields are not empty
    requiredFields.each(function () {
        var t = $(this);
        if (isEmpty(t.val())) {
            fieldsValidate = false;
            if (!t.hasClass('err')) {
                addErrorMessage(t);
            }
        }
    });

    // check that email is valid
    console.log(isValidEmail(emailValue) + ' valid?');

    if (!isValidEmail(emailValue)) {
        fieldsValidate = false;
        if (!email.hasClass('err')) {
            addErrorMessage(email);
            console.log('mail NOT ok');
        }
    }
    console.log(fieldsValidate + ' before return');
    return fieldsValidate;
};

$('input, textarea').blur(clearError);

$(".submit").click(function() { return validateForm(this.form) });
```

I have made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tucado/bhHau/1/) but it doesn't contain the actual php (I don't know ca I use php in jsFiddle.

So where the problem is: Using the form on this page: [demo page](http://tucadomusic.co.uk/ave/test-form.html) (please scroll down and click on ADD NEW TESTIMONIAL - following problems appear:

1. After not filling all fields and clicking submit - it slides the form up (I want it to slide up only when the form is filled correctly)
2. When I remove the slideToggle script -  Even if its not filled right and you click on ADD NEW TSTIMONIAL... again to send this form and won't fill it, then it will send the actual message (empty), so it ignores the validation form. To test this instance, please just put anything on the msg field and leave other ones empty. It will ignore them and send the form after couple of clicks on the submit button.

What could be the reason? where the problems are? weird situation and difficult to explain in easier way. Thanks for your support on this one.

Comment: It does its validation correctly here! what's the problem?

Comment: it did validate correctly until I added php + the jquery on top of html. the validation script itself validates correctly. The demo website presents the issue. scripts itself look ok to me. No idea what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
 echo "<h6>Message sent successfully. Thank you for your feedback.</h6>";
```

try

```
echo "sent";
```

Then in your jquery script:

```
success: function(msg){
               if(msg == 'sent'){
                        $('#response_goes_here').html('Message sent successfully. Thank you for your feedback.');
                        $("#feedback-form").slideToggle(200);
                    } else {
                     $('#response_goes_here').html('Error. Mail not sent!');
                   }
```

}

And this

```
 if(!$_POST['msg'] || $_POST['name'] || $_POST['email']){
                 echo "<h6>Error sending e-mail<h6>";
                 exit;
          }
```

Will return error everytime name or email is completed :D. try

```
if(empty($_POST['msg']) || empty($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['email'])){
   echo "<h6>Error sending e-mail<h6>";
                     exit;
}
```

Comment: thanks. I have tried that, but it doesnt actually slidetoogle the form also doesn't send it for some reason. Also doesn't display the message message sent successfully....

Comment: tweak the code. msg is the message returned by php script. you have to check that. in your place, i would make a function, instead of that echo in php, i would return true or false and i would check if msg === true, (div id).html(my long message); else etc. or, just replace what is in echo with something like 'working', easier to validate. if you don't get it, i will write a code sample to try

Comment: if you could write a code then I will understand, not sure what you mean. thank you for your help.

Comment: thanks this seems to work - almost. the problem here is that it keeps the error message, even if everything is OK. Also doesn't slideToggle when email sent. but almost there. thank you

Comment: Have you modified in your php script?

Comment: Ah, sorry working now :) I must have done something wrong first time. Great job !! thanks

Comment: you're welcome, anytime. you can always contact me for further problems :)

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of errors:

Replace `$(function () {` with `(function ($) {`

Don't call `submitmyform` on click of button

Replace

```
<button type="button" class="submit" onClick="submitmyform();">Send your feedback</button>
```

With

```
<button type="button" class="submit">Send your feedback</button>
```

Don't validate on button click, instead call form submit and do validation in submit handler. If form is valid then call `submitmyform`. As form will be submitted using ajax, submit handler will always return false. To do this replace below code:

```
$(".submit").click(function() { return validateForm(this.form) });
```

With below code and try:

```
$(".submit").click(function() { 
    $("#myform").submit();
});

$("#myform").submit(function() {
    if (validateForm(this)) {
        console.log('valid');
        submitmyform();
    } else {
        console.log('invalid');
    }
    return false;
});
```

Updated PHP Code:

```
if (empty($_POST['msg']) || empty($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['email'])) {
    echo "<h6>Error sending e-mail<h6>";
    exit();
}
$receip = "office@avehire.co.uk";
$subj = "Testimonial";
$bodymsg = "Name: " . $_POST['name'] . "\n"
        . "Company: " . $_POST['company'] . "\n"
        . "Email: " . $_POST['email'] . "\n"
        . "Message: " . $_POST['msg'] . "\n";

$email = $_POST['email'];
if (mail($receip, $subj, $bodymsg, 'From: Contact <' . $email . '>')) {
    echo "<h6>Message sent successfully. Thank you for your feedback.</h6>";
} else {
    echo "<h6>Error occurred while sending email.</h6>";
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately. Doesn't display any message. when i click to send again it displays 'error sending e-mail' even when all fields are filled. :( I have made all replacements as you suggested @manoj.admlab but unfortunately not working.

Comment: You are always getting 'error sending e-mail' because of errors in `PHP` code, answer update for `PHP` code